# Is it ok to remove all Python?

Tags: pi-3, python-3, python-2.x

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I installed Raspbian on it using NOOBS. I want to use Python 3.6 only. Is it ok if I uninstall both Python 3.5 and 2.7? Will there be no system problems? If I yes, how do I uninstall them?

Comment: `apt remove ...` However as per joan's answer this probably won't work for python 2, in which case you should leave it be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried uninstalling them one by one but I encountered a problem. The system won't boot correctly. I think both versions of Python is needed for Raspbian to run correctly.

Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 3):

You have not told us which system you use so it is speculation as to whether you will have problems or not.

I believe Debian based systems use Python 2 for system purposes.

Comment: I am using Raspbian for my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. Installed it through NOOBS.

Comment: Joan is likely correct, in which case the system simply won't let you remove it.  Do not try to force the issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the SDcard copier to copy the SDcard, remove each python package one at a time. If anything goes wrong, you have your SD card. If nothing goes wrong, clear the other SD card.

Comment: Packages are installed with dependency chains, and the package manager (`apt`) will not let you remove critical software without some roadblocks.

Comment: And therefor you know it is needed and you don't uninstall it. @goldilocks